# How can I get this program to trigger cv.waitKey() on its own in order to exit this loop?

Tags: python, opencv, pynput

**Problem:** I want the code to exit the loop once a rectangle is drawn but it's not working!  I have a loop with cv.waitKey() waiting to be pressed.  How can I exit the loop from some external initiator?  I am building off of someone else's code btw.

I tried using pynput but for some reason it isn't working... Here is the code and I would like to exit the while loop once the rectangle is drawn on the image.

```
import numpy as np
import cv2 as cv
from pynput.keyboard import Key, Controller
from time import sleep



class Interface:

    def __init__(self, image):

        self.ix = 0
        self.iy = 0
        self.ix2 = 0
        self.iy2 = 0
        self.drawing = False
        self.before_rect = image.copy()
        self.image = image.copy()
        self.result_img = image.copy()

    # Adding Function Attached To Mouse Callback
    def draw(self,event,x,y,flags,params):

        # Left Mouse Button Down Pressed
        if(event==1):
            self.drawing = True
            self.ix = x
            self.iy = y
        # Moving mouse
        if(event==0):
            self.ix2 = x
            self.iy2 = y
            if self.drawing == True:
                self.image = (self.before_rect).copy()
                cv.rectangle(self.image, pt1=(self.ix, self.iy), pt2=(x, y), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=3)
        # Left Mouse Button Up
        if(event==4):
            if self.drawing == True:
                self.ix2 = x
                self.iy2 = y
                # For Drawing Rectangle
                cv.rectangle(self.result_img, pt1=(self.ix, self.iy), pt2=(x, y), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=3)
                self.image = (self.result_img).copy()


                '''Here is the issue!!! How do I solve it?'''

                # Doesn't do anything to exit the loop like I wanted :(
                print('pressed') # (output to terminal) -> pressed 
                keyboard = Controller()
                keyboard.press(Key.esc)
                sleep(.01)
                keyboard.release(Key.esc)

            self.drawing = False

    def get_boxes(self):

        cv.namedWindow("Window")

        # Adding Mouse CallBack Event
        cv.setMouseCallback("Window", self.draw)

        # Starting The Loop So Image Can Be Shown
        while (True):
            cv.imshow("Window", self.image)
            if cv.waitKey(5) & 0xFF == 27:
                break
        cv.destroyAllWindows()

        return


# Making The Blank Image
orig = np.zeros((512,512,3))

# Start drawing boxes!
obj = Interface(orig)
obj.get_boxes()
```

-it is executing the pynput keypress (I know since it prints 'pressed'), but it isn't producing any effect on the code.  sad.

*Thank you for the helppppp!* ~(^ \_`_/ ^)~

Comment: Instead of implicitly breaking the loop through keys, I think it's better to use *flags*, i.e. booleans that tell you when to break the loop. This should be easy especially since you are writing in a class. In your `__init__` function define a flag `self.loop_running = True`, set that to false after the rectangle is drawn, and change `while True` to `while self.loop_running` in your `def get_boxes(self):` function

Comment: Oh you are so right!  Thank you!

Comment: Great, does it work? If so, I will add it as an answer, it may be useful to others then as well. :)

Comment: See my answer below. You may accept it as an answer if you are satisfied with it.

Comment: I also realized I literally just reinvented `cv.selectROI` x'D all I have to do is `return (self.ix, self.iy, self.ix2-self.ix, self.iy2-self.iy)` and I might as well rename `get_boxes` to `selectROI` lmao

Answer (score 0, accepted):

### Use boolean flags

Instead of implicitly breaking the loop through key commands, I think it is better and more Pythonic to use *flags*, i.e. boolean variables that tell you when to run or to break a loop. This is especially easy for you since you are working with an instantiated object, that is an instance that shares the same scope among its methods (through the `self` parameter).

For example, in your `__init__()` function, you can initialize a variable `self.loop_running = True`, which is defined upon instantiation.

Subsequently, in your `draw()` method, set this flag to `False` whenever you want to trigger a loop break, example:

```
def drawing(*args):
    # some code
    if self.drawing:
        self.ix2 = x
        self.iy2 = y
        # For Drawing Rectangle
        cv.rectangle(self.result_img, pt1=(self.ix, self.iy), pt2=(x, y), color=(255, 255, 255), thickness=3)
        self.image = (self.result_img).copy()
        # set flag to false ->
        self.loop_running = False
```

Then in your final function where you call the main loop, change `while True` to `while self.loop_running` instead!:

```
def get_boxes(self):

    cv.namedWindow("Window")

    # Adding Mouse CallBack Event
    cv.setMouseCallback("Window", self.draw)

    # Starting The Loop So Image Can Be Shown
    while self.loop_running:
        cv.imshow("Window", self.image)
    cv.destroyAllWindows()

    return
```